# what's practical example / use case SELECT SLEEP() for DBA

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sleep

I don't know how to use `SELECT SLEEP()`. It looks like a dirty hack.

I found an interesting question [How and when to use `SLEEP()` correctly in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284524/how-and-when-to-use-sleep-correctly-in-mysql). The answer is developer oriented:

> If you don't want to `SELECT SLEEP(1);`, you can also `DO SLEEP(1)`; It's
>   useful for those situations in procedures where you don't want to see
>   output.

what are examples for DBA?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a "go slower" button to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used it to create backups where I sleep until I can get a process ID from the processlist that is holding a database lock. I mentioned this idea back on `Apr 17, 2011` in my answer to the post [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)

I wrote the answer to another post `Jun 20, 2012` that has the actual code where I demonstrated the use of `SELECT SLEEP` ([Safest way to perform mysqldump on a live system with active reads and writes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/safest-way-to-perform-mysqldump-on-a-live-system-with-active-reads-and-writes/19533#19533))

I have done things like this in the OS making physical backups using bash. I simply did the same in MySQL itself.