# Backup live mariadb

Tags: mariadb-5.5

I want to take a dump from a live mariadb database, but I need during the backup process to stop any kind of insert or update so as my backup to  be the latest data image from my database.

Is this possible and how ?

Comment: use database replication, where your main database is master and the second is a child. and there is also https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup

Comment: @nbk I don't see how these two options will stop insert and updates during backup.

Comment: Oh sorry,then you need to loock the database https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/safest-way-to-perform-mysqldump-on-a-live-system-with-active-reads-and-writes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a live System use database replication, where your main database is master and the second is a child. and there is also [percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup)

Additional information for example for examlpe lockinfg the databse see

[Safest way to perform mysqldump on a live system with active reads and writes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/safest-way-to-perform-mysqldump-on-a-live-system-with-active-reads-and-writes)